# Unable to accept X-Client-Type header at root level in Springdoc OpenAPI while migrating from Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am currently migrating from Swagger to Springdoc OpenAPI. In Swagger, I used to accept both Jwt token and X-Client-Type header at the root level and passed both fields for each API. However, I am not able to achieve the same thing in Springdoc OpenAPI.

I am able to accept the Jwt token header, but I am unable to accept the X-Client-Type header. I have tried to define the header at the API operation level, but it is tedious as I have to define the header for each operation.

Is there a way to define the X-Client-Type header at the root level for all API requests in Springdoc OpenAPI, similar to how it was defined in Swagger? I have looked through the documentation and searched for references online, but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me.

Any help or reference links would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I am unable to share the piece of code due to privacy reasons.

Thank you in advance.
[Using Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXY5c.png)
[While using springdoc openAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLByo.png)

I have searched for resources online but have not found any useful information yet. I am unsure whether it is possible to define the header at the root level in Springdoc OpenAPI.